# Cannot download using fpassthru

Tags: php, azure, download

I'm trying to serve a file for download to a user, and I'm having trouble with fpassthru. The function I'm using to download a file is:
http://pastebin.com/eXDpgUqq
Note that the file is successfully created from a blob, and is in fact the file I want the user to download. The script exits successfully, and reports no errors, but the file is not downloaded. I can't for the life of me think what's wrong.
EDIT: I removed the error suppression from fopen(), but it still reports no error. Somehow the data in the output buffer is never being told to be downloaded by the browser.

Comment: Two things: (1) do not output anything while serving the file, as this is cause invalid data. And (2) have you checked the result of FPASSTHROUGH - as per documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) it should return either FALSE or number bytes passed through.
if it returns false, then turn your error reporting to E_ALL and see what is happaning.

Comment: Here's the new function after making your suggested modifications: http://pastebin.com/fT7DFdvS
which only outputs:
`0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPgADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAXwAAA` etc.
if there is a different way to see the return value of fpassthru, that might help, but I've been getting this nonsense output whenever the header()s are included. Additionally, there are no errors reported.

Comment: do **not** print_r fpassthrough! it will send the FALSE or number of bytes to the output buffer.
try changing your call to fpassthrou to :

ob_end_clean();
@fpassthru($file);

ob_end_flush();
fclose($file);

Comment: Here are my revisions:
http://pastebin.com/RtCb3fuF
It still prints the same gobbledygook to the response (even though I'm not printing anything?), and that response does appear to have roughly the same size as the file, but the file is not downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to download the file by passing a stream obtained with the Azure API directly to fpassthru, without creating a file. Unfortunately, I can't show the code because it belongs to a project that I have finished working on and the code is no longer available to me.

Comment: Glad to see you have fixed this issue. Without knowing your detailed code, I suppose your solution is moreorless like what I said in my item #3.

Comment: similar, but it doesn't involve a browser redirect

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code (without the blob part), and it worked fine. I can download a binary file. Based on my experience, here are something to check:

- Has the file been completely saved before you initiate the reading? Check the return value of file_put_contents.
- How large is the file? fpassthru reads the whole file into memory. If the file is too large, memory might be insufficient. Please refer to http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10330609-RESOLVED-php-driven-file-download-using-fpassthru for more information.
- Instead of downloading the file to local server (reading the whole file into server’s memory, and letting the client download the file from the server), you can create an SAS URL, and simply redirect the browser to the URL. Azure will take care of download automatically. You many want to refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureossds/archive/2015/05/12/generating-shared-access-signature-sas-using-php.aspx for a sample.